# Soft body simulation wasn't rendered

Tags: rendering, soft-body

I made two object ; one was for soft-body simulation, and another one was for mesh-deform. Set the simulation to both and made animation.

But, I rendered animation and checked it, the simulation had not worked. I can see simulation at view port correctly, but at rendering, I can't see it.

Could you tell me some idea for this problem?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, I would recommend that you *bake* the cloth simulation before you render it. If you already have, try baking it again.

If it still doesn't show up in the render, check to make sure "Render visibility" (the camera icon) is enabled in the modifiers panel for all of the objects associated with the simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you say, I had not baked simulation before render animation. Thank you for your help and kindness.